# How to insert registration form value in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I create a new page which has the simple html form,but i dont khow where to post the form value and insert query.

Please clarify the location..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595821/wordpress-custom-registration-form


Please see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to insert registration form value in wordpress?

Forms are an integral part of a website. While there are lots of wordpress plugins available to create custom forms, most of them are not up to the task. It is very easy to create a form in WordPress, provided you have a fair knowledge of php, html and js. Let me show you how it’s done.

***What Pages Are:***

1. Pages are for content that is less time-dependent than Posts.
2. Pages can be organized into pages and subpages.
3. Pages can use different Page Templates which can include Template
   Files, Template Tags and other PHP code.
4. Pages may have a more complex array of readily available display
   adjustments when using sophisticated Themes with extensive
   customization.
5. In essence, Pages are for non-blog content. It is possible to remove
   all or most Posts from a WordPress installation, and thus to create
   a standard non-blog website.

***http://tipsforwordpress.com/wordpress/add-custom-field-to-register-form/***

***http://shibulijack.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/create-custom-forms-in-wordpress/***

***http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages***

***http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages***

***if same as stackoverflow communities to use like:***

***https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/***

***sample registration programs:***

***http://www.antimath.info/wordpress/wordpress-registration-form-in-a-regular-page/***

***http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1341-wordpress-profile-builder-a-front-end-user-registration-login-and-edit-profile-plugin/***

***http://www.inkthemes.com/how-you-can-easily-create-customized-form-in-wordpress/09/***

***Static Front Page:***

*This is a traditional static HTML site model with a fixed front page and content placed in Pages, rarely if ever using posts, categories, or tags.*

***sample one:***

```
form action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_login" value="Username" id="user_login" class="input" />
    <input type="text" name="user_email" value="E-Mail" id="user_email" class="input"  />
    <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" />
</form>
```

***http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/***

Comment: actually i am not using any plugin for form submission.please explain where i can add my connection file and insert query.and how can i connect my html page to connection page.

Answer (score 0):

A better place to ask WordPress questions is probably on [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

in case you want to handle this yourself, here's the code:

See this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/front-end-register-form/7151#7151